# Why data is not being added to database? Entity Framework, Blazor wasm

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, blazor-webassembly

I have 3 tables in my database: `Ingredient`, `IngredientRecipe` and `Recipe`. Adding data to `Ingredient` works correctly. `IngredientRecipe` is for making relation between `Ingredient` and `Recipe`. When I want to add a `Recipe` to database, nothing happens. No errors, no data in the database.

My error message:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
```

`DbContext` class:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Ingredient> IngredientsTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IngredientRecipe> IngredientRecipesTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> RecipesTable { get; set; }
}
```

Ingredient, IngredientRecipe and Recipe:

```
public class Ingredient : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Kcal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IngredientRecipe> IngredientRecipe { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientRecipe : BaseEntity
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<IngredientRecipe> ListOfIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my form code:

```
@page "/recipes/create"
@inject IIngredientRepository ingredientRepository
@inject IRecipeRepository recipeRepository
@inject NavigationManager navManager

<div class="container col-12">
    <EditForm Model="Recipe" OnValidSubmit="SaveRecipe">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save recipe</button>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-control">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Recipe.Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <TableTemplate Items="ListOfIngredients">
            <TableHeader>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Kcal</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </TableHeader>
            <RowTemplate Context="ingredient">
                <td>@ingredient.Name</td>
                <td>@ingredient.Kcal</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(()=>SetTheAmount(ingredient))">Add</button>
                </td>
            </RowTemplate>
        </TableTemplate>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        List of ingredients
        <br />
        @if (ListOfIngredientAmounts.Any())
        {
            <TableTemplate Items="ListOfIngredientAmounts">
                <TableHeader>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </TableHeader>
                <RowTemplate Context="ingredient">
                    <td>@ingredient.Ingredient.Name</td>
                    <td>@ingredient.Amount</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </RowTemplate>
            </TableTemplate>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@if (IngredientAmount.Ingredient != null)
{
    <p>Ingredient Id: @IngredientAmount.IngredientId | Name: @IngredientAmount.Ingredient.Name | Amount: @IngredientAmount.Amount</p>
    <EditForm Model="IngredientAmount" OnValidSubmit="AddIngredientToIngredientAmountList">
        <div class="form-group">
            Value
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="IngredientAmount.Amount" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add to list</button>
    </EditForm>
}

@code{
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; } = new Recipe();

    public List<Ingredient> ListOfIngredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

    public IngredientRecipe IngredientAmount { get; set; } = new IngredientRecipe();

    public List<IngredientRecipe> ListOfIngredientAmounts { get; set; } = new List<IngredientRecipe>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ListOfIngredients = await ingredientRepository.GetListOfIngredients();
    }

    private void SetTheAmount(Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        IngredientAmount = new IngredientRecipe();
        IngredientAmount.IngredientId = ingredient.Id;
        IngredientAmount.Recipe = Recipe;
        IngredientAmount.RecipeId = Recipe.Id;
        IngredientAmount.Ingredient = ingredient;
    }

    private void AddIngredientToIngredientAmountList()
    {
        ListOfIngredientAmounts.Add(IngredientAmount);
        IngredientAmount = new IngredientRecipe();
    }

    private async void SaveRecipe()
    {
        if (ListOfIngredientAmounts.Any())
        {
            Recipe.ListOfIngredients = ListOfIngredientAmounts;

            await recipeRepository.CreateRecipe(Recipe);

            ListOfIngredientAmounts = new List<IngredientRecipe>();
            Recipe = new Recipe();
            navManager.NavigateTo("/recipes");
        }
    }
}
```

And my repository and controller responsible for post:

```
public async Task CreateRecipe(Recipe recipe)
{
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, recipe);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(Recipe recipe)
{
    context.RecipesTable.Add(recipe);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return recipe.Id;
}
```

And here is link to GitHub https://github.com/szymonJag/CookBook

Comment: You aren't checking for an Exception on `SaveChangesAsync()` so how do you know there aren't any errors?

Comment: Could you expand? I change code like this but i dont know if i did it correctly
 `try { await context.SaveChangesAsync(); } catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine($"{e} exception");}
`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004291/dbcontext-savechangesasync-exception-handling) for a discussion about exception handling with `SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: Still dont know if i did it correctly `try { await context.SaveChangesAsync(); } catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException) { throw; }` Please correct me if it is possible

Comment: So, drop a breakpoint on SaveChangesAsync() and step through your code.  Is it throwing an Exception?

Comment: I found problem why I didn't have error message. I just edited the post with error message. If u could take a look at it, and give me some information how to prevent this type of errors. Thank you for help

Comment: So the issue is with related navigational properties being mapped to json, A recipe will have a collection of IngredientRecipes, each one of those will have Ingredient  oproperty and Recipe propterty, each on of those will have a collection of IngredientRecipes... etc. This can be solved by having a dto objec that you select into

Comment: Maybe you know some good articles or tutorials how to properly make a dto object which will resolve my problem? I can't find reliable informations which would help me